# HTTP error 500.19 - Cannot read configuration file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

In one of my ASP.NET apps, all of a sudden I am unable to run it in Visual Studio 2013 due to the error displayed below. It appears that it is trying to open the web.config from a path that doesn't even exist. All of my project code, including web.config, are located under C:\Projects\SourceCode\AFEManager\Trunk\AFEManager.Web. I've found a number of posts here from users experiencing a similar error, but the solutions seem to vary and none I've found so far seem applicable to my situation. I looked in that TraceLogFiles directory and the most recent log file there is five days old so it obviously hasn't been logging anything since I've been having this issue. Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Same error here, did you fixed it ?

Comment: I think I just found a solution yesterday afternoon. I'll be updating the post shortly. Unfortunately, it seems this same error can occur under a variety of circumstances so it's very possible that my solution won't work for you.

Answer (score 33):

In my case I deleted all folders in D:\My Documents\My Web Sites\ before 
Then I caught the error 
There is a file .vs\config\applicationhost.config in my solution folder 
It contains reference to the deleted folder. So, I deleted applicationhost.config and then pressed 'Create Virtual Directory' button in my project property Web page. It was recreated the file and the folder

Comment: Deleting applicationhost.config and creating new virtual directory worked

Comment: Worked for me: Removed .vs/ folder inside your solution directory.

Comment: Thanks! I was asked to revisit and app I made last year and I had this issue. I had moved the app to another folder to commit to source control and it was complaining about not finding web.config (which I don't even have, instead I have an appsettings.json) on a folder that doesn't exist anymore.
You saved me quite some time!

Answer (score 21):

I had this issue when I moved the project folder to the new machine. The problem is that the VS has the site registered in its config file (`applicationhost.config`) inside `.vs/` folder but did not create folder inside `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Web Sites\`. If you just click Create Virtual Directory inside the project properties (Web tab) it will not be enough.

1. First close your VS and remove `.vs/` folder inside your solution directory
2. Reopen VS and click Create Virtual Directory inside the project properties (Web tab) - VS will register the site again and create corresponding folder inside `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Web Sites\`

Comment: thanks, deleting .vs folder solved an issue in my case

Answer (score 19):

I've been able to resolve this issue even though I can't say I fully understand all of the details. I'll attempt to describe the situation the best I understand it and hopefully others with greater insight can add further clarification.

After having been doing all of my development on my workstation, it was suggested that I begin doing this work in a new VM environment that had been set up for me. So I installed VS 2013 there and copied my source code from various projects over there. However, rather than follow my previous local path convention of C:\Projects\SourceCode[ProjectName]... this time I decided to use the directories that are set up during the VS install, c:\users[MyUser]\My Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects[ProjectName]. Sometime shortly thereafter, our infrastructure team made a change so that my home directory, c:\users\rmayer, was now being pointed to a common network drive, \totalsafety\TSUsers\rmayer. Everything continued to work without any issues.

However, due to various difficulties I had working in this VM environment, I decided to return to doing my development work on my workstation using the original local paths for my source code. This is when I began encountering the errors described above whenever I would try to run my code through VS. What I've begun to learn is that there is an applicationhost.config file that IIS Express uses located here: \totalsafety\TSUsers\rmayer\My Documents\IISExpress\config. It contains entries for each of my web projects; the one relevant to this issue had a section which looked like this:

```
        <site name="AFEManager.Web-Site" id="8">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\rmayer\Documents\My Web Sites\AFEManager.Web-Site" />
            </application>
            <application path="/AFEManager" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\SourceCode\AFEManager\Trunk\AFEManager.Web" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:19257:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

The physical path attribute listed under applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" at that time was set based on the local path I had been using at the time I was working in the VM environment. Now that this one file is being shared regardless of whether I'm working locally or within the VM due to the move of the users' home directories, this path is invalid when I'm working from my workstation. By updating this path to C:\Projects\SourceCode\AFEManager\Trunk\AFEManager.Web, it now works correctly from my workstation.

Again, I have a limited understanding of how this is supposed to work, but what it's telling me is that I will be unable to do development work from multiple environments (not that I want to any longer) unless the local paths are consistent between all of them. If I'm correct about this, this seems like a less than ideal design.

Comment: That was a great hint. We had cloned a machine and then renamed the physical folder to match the environment. Forgot to update the path for an virtual application underneath.

Answer (score 8):

I changed the virtual directory path in vs\config\applicationhost.config inside the solution folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you. If you are the author of the question, you can also mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the project was located on network not my local disk. After copying the project to local, the issue was resolved. Hope it can save someones time who has the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Delete .VS folders that Visual studio created.
It might be hidden in your project structure.
Unhide the folders and look for .vs folder and delete that folder and rebuild the application.

Comment: Only solution that worked for me. And was simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the path for the web.config to its real path in applicationhost.config file. This file is located in /.vs/config folder.

After changing the path in this file, save it and restart the project, it solved my issue.

This is happening because I have different work stations, but the project is saving in different folders.

Answer (score 2):

Most simplest way to solve this issue.

Approximate reason to arise this error is copy project from another pc.

Solution:

- Step 01: From Visual Studio Solution Explorer, Right click on your project and choose Open Folder in File Explorer.
- Step 02: Open .vs folder (Hidden Folder) and
  you will get 2 folder named config and another one is named as
  your_project_name/config.
- Step 03: Both config folder will contain a
  file named applicationhost.
- Step 04: Open both applicationhost file using notepad and find the directory showing in error screen (Config
  File \?\C:\User\hp\Documents\My Web
  Sites\YourProjectName\web.config)
- Step 05: Just replace this
  directory according to your pc directory. Example, in my pc I have
  changed as below:

C:\Users\Sydur Rahman\Documents\My Web Sites\MyProjectName-Site
to
C:\Users\hp\Documents\My Web Sites\MyProjectName-Site

Note: Please make sure you have changed in both applicationhost file.

That's all. Now your project will run as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you PongGod!! I am not able to comment on your answer but I wanted to post anyway since I had the exact same issue while running an instance of [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/). In my case, everything had been running great until I found a bunch of old project files located in:

```
%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Web Sites\
```

And started deleting them for no apparent reason. I then tried to start up Orchard from Visual Studio in debug mode and received the error message above. After applying the same fix to my applicationhost.config file, everything is working fine now.

In my case, I am assuming that the directories got mixed up because I had initially ran the default Orchard files from Visual Studio and from Web Matrix. Then later on, I downloaded the full source files and began running the files from a completely different directory. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad my experience was helpful to you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution i have found.

https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/i-asked-for-a-vs-folder-and-the-vs-team-gave-it-to-me/

(1)Find the **applicationhost.config** file in **|YourSolution|\.vs\config**

[image]

(2)Modify the VirtualDirectory PhysicalPath To your project.

(3)Restart solution. Start project.

(4)If it's still not working, try to check setting in your IISExpress config. If there is not site setting, copy And paste the setting to **|UserOnYourComputer|\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config**

[image]

(5)Change the id to other id which not be used in IISExpress applicationhost.config.

(6)Start your project.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and I resolve it quite simply. My issue was arose after when I perform a merge operation in git repository, after merge operation Visual Studio some how changed my default project URL to the default URL of my partner's computer from where he pushed the last time in to my repository. 
So here is how I resolved this error:

1. Simply go to the properties of the project.
2. From the left vertically aligned menu, select Web.
3. After you will Project url   and a text box containing the default port number, now just aside that textbox there is a button "Create Virtual Directory".
4. Press that button and there you go.
   It will again point the default url the current working folder of your project.

Hope it works for you all :)

Answer (score 0):

After all this answers I find my solution. Delete te WebSite in the IIS and recriate. Why? Because I had create de website before installed the framework 4.5 and URL Rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project dir:

```
..\\{ProjectDir}\\.vs\\{ProjectName}\\config
```

Then delete the `applicationhost.config` file and recompile your solution.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

**This steps helped me to get over this error**
1.In Windows Explorer, locate the web.config file that is associated with the Web site.

2.Right-click the web.config file

3.Click Properties.

4.Click the Security tab, and then click Edit.

5.Click Add.

6.In the Enter the object names to select box, type computername\IIS_IUSRS, click Check Names, and then click OK.

Note* Computername is a placeholder for the computer name.

7.Click to select the Read check box, and then click OK.

8.In the Web.config Properties dialog box, click OK.