# The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. (with a "catch"...)

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Another user in my organization put a folder with source code on a central server. I copied the source code to my local machine and when I try to run the application in VS on my local machine I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x80070005
Config Error       Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
Config File    \\?\UNC\...\users\username\My Web Sites\Website1\web.config
```

The issue is with the file location of the problematic .config file:

**\\?\UNC...\users\username\My Web Sites\Website1\web.config**

This location does not exist on my local machine. I have confirmed with the other user that it **does** exist on his machine - so it appears that the application is referencing a file location that simply does not exist. My suspicion is that there is some kind of folder/cache that needs to be cleared out, but I don't know what to do in this situation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up actually finding a duplicate question with an answer regarding deleting an applicationhost.config file and then recreating it in VS:

[HTTP error 500.19 - Cannot read configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787480/http-error-500-19-cannot-read-configuration-file)